# Covariance of a random variable and its mean estimator

Tags: random, covariance, means

I was wondering if there is a common solution for the covariance of a random variable $x[n]$ (i.i.d) and its mean estimator $\hat{\theta}$. Mathematically,

\begin{equation}
\sigma^2 \left ( x[n],\hat{\theta} \right )
\end{equation}

Where,

\begin{equation}
\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]
\end{equation}

Thank you.